# ruby httparty get response url or id after post

Tags: ruby, httparty

How can I get the response url or id from a rails project with httparty in a separate script after doing a post?

ruby script:

```
  HTTParty.post('http://localhost:3000/change_logs', parameters)
```

response.body and all the others ones do not show the url and the response id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works for me, there's probably a better way to do this though..

```
get_change_log_id = HTTParty.post('http://localhost:3000/change_logs.xml', parameters).to_a

get_change_log_id.each do |r|
  r.each do |sub|
    sub2 = sub.to_a
      sub2.each do |s|
        if s.index "id"
          @change_log_id = s.to_s.sub(/[i]/, '').sub(/[d]/, '')
        end
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: yes there was an easier way:

results = HTTParty.post('http://localhost:3000/change_logs.xml', parameters)

change_log_id = results.parsed_response["change_log"].values_at("id")

Answer (score 32):

Two years later, I found a way to access the last URI from the `request` attribute on the `response`:

```
url      = "http://example.com/redirects/to/www"
response = HTTParty.get(url)
response.request.last_uri.to_s
# => "http://www.example.com"
```

Comment: If you're wanting to do this without getting the body of the final destination. i.e. if you're wanting to just get the final URL, you can replace the `HTTPParty.get` call with `HTTParty.head(url, { :maintain_method_across_redirects => true })`

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, that information is not kept by HTTParty.  When it encounters a redirect, it will follow the redirect and return the result of that request.  It will not save any of the information from the original request.

The good news is, behavior like this is (usually) predictable.  Web apps generally redirect to the same things after a post request to a URL.

But if you really want to do this, you're going to have to use the net/http library that comes with Ruby.  It's not much harder than HTTParty though, so it's not much more work.

Comment: thanks for the response, that makes sense - however I did figure out a way to do it.. it's a little weird though